# Fancybox gallery loop issue

Tags: wordpress, twig, fancybox

I have a problem with this code for a `fancybox` gallery which its showing all images across the page, when should be visible just the first one and then others, when you click.

How do i stop from showing all images and show just the first one before click?

```
<code>

    {% for slide in wp.get_post_meta(post.ID, '_property_slides', TRUE) %}
        <div class="carousel property">
            <div class="preview">
                <a rel="galeria{{ post.ID }}" href="{{ slide.imgurl }}">
                     <img src="{{ slide.imgurl }}" alt="">
                 </a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.preview -->

            <div class="content">
                <ul>
                    {% for slide in wp.get_post_meta(post.ID, '_property_slides', TRUE) %}
                        {% if loop.first %}
                            <li class="active" >
                        {% else %}
                            <li>
                        {% endif %}
                        <img src="{{ slide.imgurl }}" alt="">
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>

                <a id="carousel-prev" href="#">{{ wp.__('Previous', 'aviators') }}</a>
                <a id="carousel-next" href="#">{{ wp.__('Next', 'aviators') }}</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.content -->
        </div><!-- /.carousel -->
    {% endfor %}

</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the first line:

```
// delete this line {% for slide in wp.get_post_meta(post.ID, '_property_slides', TRUE) %}
{% if wp.get_post_meta(post.ID, '_property_slides', TRUE) %} //use this one
```

and the last one:

```
// delete this line {% endfor %}
{% end %}
```

Comment: Hi marcos, didn´t work the whole site goes blank, i saw in console of firefox and show internal server error. thanks for helping me, i don´t know if there`s anything else that you can do.

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem would be, since it's theme you bought not a standard implementation neither of Wordpress or twig. You could try reaching the seller of the theme for help!

Comment: I already did it, theme support isn´t the best, that´s why i was looking help. I really appreciate all what you did, at least im not so far now from where i was to fix it. thanks